# ajax call to set/update session shopping cart does not fire

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables, shopping-cart

I've used stackoverflow to answer almost every question I ever had on php scripting, and it's here I learned most about ajax calls, jquery and javascript related problems. I've got one now however I cannot seem to find the answer to, and i'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Basically, it's a shopping cart which stores the product id in the session using an ajax call - after the ajax call is successful a shopping cart tray should appear if it was hidden (when it hasnt been set). The issue is however, that even the most basic ajax call breaks. My HTML looks like this (per product), shortened the url's as they do not matter for the example, they just link to the product page:

```
<article>
<a href="#">
    <img nopin="nopin" alt="#" src="#">
</a>
<h5>
    <a href="#">Product name</a>
</h5>
<p class="price">
    <a href="#">&euro; 0,00</a>
</p>                
<input type="button" name="bestelknop" id="bestelknop" data-id="'.$product['p_id'].'" value="In winkelmandje">
</article>
```

I use the ajax call to parse to a php file which only function is to update the cart:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['p_id'])) {
$p_id = $_POST['p_id'];
$_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
}
?>
```

The ajax call then looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#bestelknop").click(function() {
    var p_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
    url : '/paginas/winkelmandje/toevoegen.php',
    data: 'p_id='+p_id,
    success : function(data){
                $( "#nav-winkelmandje" ).load('/menu/winkelmandje.php'); 
                if($( "#nav-winkelmandje" ).is(':hidden')) {
       $( "#nav-winkelmandje" ).slideDown();
                }
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {alert ("Er is iets fout gegaan bij het bestellen. Druk op F5 en probeer het opnieuw.");}

    });
});
});
```

The problem now is; The first time it works. I click a product's button, the ajax call is succesfull and the resulting div is visible (showing you have a product in your cart). When i now click another product, with another data-id, the ajax call does not fire at all. I am all out of idea's as to why this would happen, does anyone else have a clue? Element inspection in chrome nor php error reporting gives me any errors.

thanks in advance,

Stephan

Edit: the button of the first product clicked remains workin. I can add more of that product to the session, but the other buttons do not work.

edit 2: the buttons were not working probably because i used the id as selector in javascript. I have changed it to the class now and the function fires, as in, I placed an alert to see if java is called, and it is. however, the ajax call does not fire and still gives no response.

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart'][$p_id]++;` this mean ?

Comment: That will set the product id as a session['cart'] key, with the quantitiy as its value. if it is not set, the quantity will be one by default.

Comment: initially, i thought adding a cache buster to your url might help. But, are you expecting the value in  your data-id attribute to change following the ajax post?

Comment: No, the data id used to identify which product to add to the session and is unique for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i fixed it. Appearantly the php processing page threw an offset error due to the ++ way of altering the quantity. I added a part on checking if the [ cart] [product id]  exists and handled accordingly, now it works.